# Showing $|\mathbb{R}| \leq$ cardinality of the set of open sets in $\mathbb{R} $

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers

Let $(O_\lambda)_{\lambda \in A}$ be the family of open sets in $\mathbb{R}$, we define $O_i= (-i, i)$.

Then {$O_i$}$_{i=1}^\infty$ is an open cover for $\mathbb{R}$.

Hence we have $\mathbb{R} \subset$ $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty O_i$ $\subset$ $(O_\lambda)_{\lambda \in A}$

Hence $|\mathbb{R}| \leq$ |$\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty O_i| $ $\leq$ $|(O_\lambda)_{\lambda \in A}|$

Just checking if this proof is correct and if there is any logical errors in between.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean $\mathbb{R} \subset \{ O_i \}_{i=1}^\infty$? Don't you mean $\mathbb{R} \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty O_i$...?

Comment: Yes sorry, it should be $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty O_i$ instead!

Comment: Well that changes everything doesn't it? Anyway you should have realize that the collection $\{ O_i \}_{i=1}^\infty$ is countable, so in the middle of your proof you wrote that $\mathbb{R}$ had at most countable cardinality...

Comment: Is that proof logically correct if I were to change it to the union of open sets?

Comment: Okay your edit is still incorrect. What does it mean now to write $\bigcup O_i \subset \{O_\lambda\}$? $\bigcup O_i$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (in fact it is $\mathbb{R}$) whereas $\{O_\lambda\}$ is a subset of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is not correct. Because literally the same proof (with "family of open sets $(G_\lambda)_{\lambda \in A}$" replaced by $G = \{(-i,i) \mid i \in \Bbb{N}\}$) would yield $|\Bbb{R}| \leq |G| = |\Bbb{N}|$, which is false.

**But** here is an idea for proving your claim: How can you construct a family $O_x$ of open sets of $\Bbb{R}$ for each $x \in \Bbb{R}$ with $O_x \neq O_y$ for $x \neq y$?

Comment: Thanks! I guess I would try to show it by $\mathbb{R} \subset$ $(O_\lambda)_{\lambda \in A}$, hence |$\mathbb{R}| \leq$ |$(O_\lambda)_{\lambda \in A}$|.

Comment: What do you mean by $\Bbb{R} \subset (O_\lambda)_\lambda$? $\Bbb{R}$ is a single **set** of real numbers, whereas $(O_\lambda)_\lambda$ is a **family** of **subsets** of $\Bbb{R}$.
$$ \qquad $$
You can simply note that the map $\Bbb{R} \to \{O \subset \Bbb{R} \mid O \text{ open}\}, x \mapsto O_x$ is injective (with $O_x$ suitably defined, which I leave to you), hence your claim follows.
$$ \qquad $$
Or what is **your** definition of $|A| \leq |B|$?

Answer (score 1):

How about ...

Define a family of open sets for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$ as $\mathscr F = $ { $(x, x+1) | x \in \mathbb{R}$}.

You can prove that the sets are distinct, as for any $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $ x \ne y$ if wlg $x < y$ then there is $ x < z < y$ and furthermore, choose $ x < z < x + 1$ so that $z \in (x, x+1)$ and $z \notin (y, y + 1)$.

Then there is a bijection between $\mathscr F  $ and $\mathbb{R}$, and $\mathscr F  $ is a subset of all open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ so $ |\mathbb{R}| = |\mathscr F| \le$ cardinality of all open sets in $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong.

$|\Bbb R|=\mathcal C$, however $|\{O_i\}_{i=1}^\infty|$ is $\omega $, i.e. it is countable.

As we know $\omega < \mathcal C$.

The relation of covering doesn't imply the relation of cardinality.